# XCHG RAX, RAX: 0x03, what does this code do and how does it work?

Tags: x86, x86-64

[*"XCHG RAX, RAX"*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1502958082) is a kind of riddle book that provides assembly code for you to reverse and undercover the meaning. Some of the examples calculate the Fibonacci sequence others bit-twiddle to toggle ASCII case. The [snippet (riddle) on `0x03`](https://www.xorpd.net/pages/xchg_rax/snip_03.html) is,

```
sub  rdx,rax
sbb  rcx,rcx
and  rcx,rdx
add  rax,rcx
```

How does this code work, and what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code boils down to,

```
rax = min(rdx,rax)
rdx = sub(rdx,rax) ; store the difference in rdx
```

That is essentially,

- `rdx - 0`         (if `rdx` is the min)
- `rdx - (rdx-rax)` (if `rax` is the min)

The `sbb` and `and` here just move into `rcx` either

- `0`
- `rdx-rax`

What determines what gets moved into `rcx`? That's determined by the result of the `sbb`. **The `sbb` is doing `reg - reg - CF`.** So you're either `AND`ing against all `1`s or all `0`s.

This is how I reasoned about it

```
# CF=0; rdx > rax
if ( rdx > rax ) {
  rdx -= rax
  rcx = 0     ; all bits off


              ; AND 0 (rcx) with anything (in rdx) is nop here.
              ; ADDing 0 (rcx) to rax is a nop
}



# CF=1; rax > rdx
else {
  rdx -= rax
  rcx = -1    ; all bits on


  rcx = rdx   ; code is rcx &= rdx
              ; remember -1 & x == x
  rax += rcx

}
```

Note regardless of the carry flag, **this code will store the difference in `rdx`**